# Does data locality matter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, browser, data-structures

I'm a game developer and I have been trying different structures to see what would give me the best results but it seems that JavaScript is mostly unaffected by data locality, meaning that processing times are within margin of error and memory usage is mostly as expected.

Does data locality matter at all in JavaScript or am I just wasting my time trying to improve certain structures?

Is it due to the sandboxed nature of the execution environment (i.e. it would matter outside the browser)?

Comment: In high-level languages like Javascript, it's hard to control data locality directly. There are lots of hidden pointers and heap objects behind the scenes.

Comment: How are you trying to change the placement of data? Re-naming or re-ordering object fields isn't going to do much. It will be easier to see differences on [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) as it's just linear memory and you're directly in control of how you access it.

Comment: Yes, data locality can help performance like it can in any other language that is executed on the same architecture. However, it's much harder to declare your structures so that it affects memory layout (unless using typed arrays directly you won't have any control over allocation), and to optimise them for a specific platform, given that your code has to run on lots of different devices. It would be considered a micro-optimisation - there are many lower hanging fruit.

Comment: Barmar: I imagined so, makes sense, thanks!

ephemient: Trying some data oriented structures - mostly playing with different implementations of entity component systems.

Bergi: Thanks, makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/memory-in-javascript-beyond-leaks-8c1d697c655c) is an interesting read. It says, in summary, low level locality optimizations are a lost cause, but big data structures, big arrays of data structures more so, should be accessed in linear order.

Coming from a C background, I tend to access a grid held in a 1D array in a Y-outer/X-inner pattern anyway, but when I have done otherwise, I can tell you from experience, it starts to lag on large grids.

So, to attempt to answer your question, and in part theorize: to the degree that this holds true, the classic structure-of-arrays rather than array-of-structures mentality might very well be performant for sufficiently large arrays of large structures with limited variable access in a given case. But I would definitely test both macro-structures if I were implementing a critical feature :)